# CanCan how to classify a function as read/update/show/create ...?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan

I have a rule for model A where a user can only :read the model. In the controller for A, I have a few functions like "show", "update" etc. (which the user can access), but also some other functions like "foo". I want the user to be able to access "foo", but I also want to call load_and_authorize for the user. Is there a way by which I can mark the function "foo" to be part of the read operation so that CanCan will succeed?